# react-native: How to create custom component dynamically and destroy it after use?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am creating a screen in functional component where I have to execute an animation when there is any event occurs ... This event could occur 1000 times when screen is open ... so I have implemented a custom component which takes position on screen and animates ....

```
const FloatingComponent = (props) => {
    
    const animationView = useSharedValue(1)
    const animationOpacityView = useSharedValue(1)
    const animationViewStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
      return {
        transform: [
          {
            translateY: withTiming(animationView.value, {
              duration: 3500
            }),

          }
        ],
        opacity: withTiming(animationOpacityView.value, {
          duration: 1500
        })
      }
    })

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log('Component animation called')
      animationView.value = -((Screen.width * 0.25))
      animationOpacityView.value = 0
    });

    return (
      <Animated.View style={[Styles.handImg, { top: props.topDistance }, animationViewStyle]}>
        <Image
          style={Styles.handImage}
          source={require('../../../assets/images/hand.png')}
        />
      </Animated.View>
    );
  };
```

To create it dynamically I implemented it like this

```
const driverFactory = (itemNumber) => {
    console.log(itemNumber)
    return (<FloatingComponent id={1} topDistance={(Screen.width * 0.25) * itemNumber} />);
  };
```

but it never show up and executes ....
while if I add this

```
<FloatingDriver id={5} topDistance={(Screen.width * 0.25) * 6} />
```

to main screen return it always executes .... but by these I can not create n number of components at any time when i receive notification ...

Answer (score 0):

I would have a parent component manage these n child components and their rendering. Here is an example showing how one might render all the components with animations and handle showing/removing them as needed.

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Animated, Button, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const Particle = ({particle: {x, y}, onFinish}) => {
  const opacity = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(opacity, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 2000,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start(() => {
      onFinish();
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <Animated.View
      style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        left: x - 10,
        bottom: y - 10,
        width: 20,
        height: 20,
        backgroundColor: 'yellow',
        opacity,
      }}
    />
  );
};

const ParticleSystem = () => {
  const [layoutRectangle, setLayoutRectangle] = React.useState();
  const [particleList, setParticleList] = React.useState([]);
  const currentRef = React.useRef();

  const addRandomParticle = React.useCallback(() => {
    if (layoutRectangle) {
      const newParticle = {
        id: Math.floor(Math.random() * Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER),
        x: Math.random() * layoutRectangle.width,
        y: Math.random() * layoutRectangle.height,
      };
      setParticleList([newParticle, ...particleList]);
    }
  }, [layoutRectangle, particleList]);

  const removeParticle = React.useCallback(
    (particle) => {
      setParticleList(particleList.filter(({id}) => id !== particle.id));
    },
    [particleList],
  );

  currentRef.current = removeParticle;

  return (
    <SafeAreaView
      style={styles.screen}
      onLayout={(event) => setLayoutRectangle(event.nativeEvent.layout)}>
      {particleList.map((particle) => (
        <Particle
          key={particle.id}
          particle={particle}
          onFinish={() => {
            currentRef.current(particle);
          }}
        />
      ))}
      <Button title="Add particle" onPress={() => addRandomParticle()} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default ParticleSystem;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  },
});
```